# Check if app on the device for intent is installed or not

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I am working on WebView that loads my site.
My problem is with the 'share' buttons, whose url isn't legal.
I tried to solved that by intent to apps but it's not working.

I don't know how to check if app is installed on the device or not.
My problem that when the app that clicked to share isn't installed on the device, my app is stopped.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // HERE YOU GET url
            ProgressBar PB1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
            PB1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (url != null && (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://"))) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                browser("javascript:window.location.reload(true)");
                return true;/// super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
                    /*Toast.makeText(getParent(), "no app found to open this link!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);*/

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         try{
            // HERE YOU GET url
            ProgressBar PB1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
            PB1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (url != null && (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://"))) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                browser("javascript:window.location.reload(true)");
                return true;/// super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

         }
        catch(Exception ignored){
    Toast.makeText(getParent(), "no app found to open this link!", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
       return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
```

Can be done this way

Answer (score 0):

add a utils to judgement this app exist. (you need a condition in AndroidManifest.xml)

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
appInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following check before starting intent:

```
 // Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
        if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(getParent(), "no app found to open this link!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```